# OkHttp callback eats up exceptions - design flaw or common practice

Tags: java, android, exception, okhttp

OkHttp library `Callback` interface is declared as

```
public interface Callback {
  void onFailure(Request request, IOException e);
  void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException;
}
```

Unhandled exceptions from onResponse method will get eaten up by `Call` class as I have recently discovered in [Callback failure for cancelled call in OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32191868/4267244)

I have few questions related to that design.

---

First, wouldn't it be better have different declaration of `onResponse` method in order to force catching exceptions in `onResponse` rather than throwing them, since they will be eaten up.

Is this design flaw in `OkHttp Callback` interface or is this kind of code common practice in Java?

---

Second, when http request reaches `onResponse` callback method I would expect that canceling request at that point should be prohibited. I would say this is a bug. Am I right?

Comment: I just discovered this and I am pissed. Spent hours debugging and later saw that the method throws exception. This is not a Java thing, just a crappy API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also struggling with this, for now I've solved it as follows:

```
 client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // AlertDialog, etc.
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                onFailure(call, new IOException("Unexpected code: " + response));
            }

                // else success

            }
        });
```

The key point is calling OnFailure inside OnResponse. I wasn't able to access the Exception in any other way (though there probably are other ways; this gives OnFailure some additional usefulness in my opinion, and it conveys intent fairly well I think). Note that OnFailure can be called for other reasons: https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/Callback.html

Comment: But how can I throw the different from IOException type?